# Copy files up 1 or 2 directories and rename them

Tags: shell-script, alpine-linux

I'm quite new to Linux, and I'm currently trying to organize files as they are downloaded.

Essentially I want to take `.srt` files from a subdirectory and move and rename them to the main directory alongside the other files.

The script I'm currently running is this:

```
find "/foo/bar" -type f -iname '*.srt' -exec sh -c '
    path="${1%/*}"; filename="${1##*/}";
    cp "${1}" "${path%/*}/${path##*/}.${filename}" ' sh_cp {} \;
```

This works well enough when the structure is like this:

```
├── Some.Folder.Name
    ├── Some.Video.Name.mkv
    └── Subs
        └── 2_Eng.srt
```

It copies `2_Eng.srt` to `Some.Folder.Name` and renames it to `Some.Folder.Name.2_Eng.srt`.

However, I've encountered some `.srt` files
that are doubly nested in folders, such as:

```
├── Some.Other.Folder.Name
    ├── Some.Other.Video.Name.mkv
    ├── Some.Other.Video.Name2.mkv
    └── Subs
        ├── Video1
        │   └── 2_Eng.srt
        └── Video2
            └── 2_Eng.srt
```

The script I'm running renames them appropriately (`Video1.2_Eng.srt`), but they're only moved up to the `Subs` directory. 
I would like them to end up in `Some.Other.Folder.Name`.

The thread I got my script from went into a little detail about the `path%/*` and `1##*/` being Shell Parameter Expansion. 
So is there a way to isolate the specific directory I would want the files to go to? While that directory name might change, it will always be the next level after `foo/bar`.

Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible?

Answer (score 0):

In a sense, what you’re asking for is impossible.
Consider: if `find` finds a name like

```
/foo/bar/Some.Other.Folder.Name/Subs/Video1/2_Eng.srt
```

what should the command do? 
You ‘‘know’’ that you want to move the file to

```
/foo/bar/Some.Other.Folder.Name/Video1.2_Eng.srt
```

— my point is that it isn’t evident from the file name.

You have to specify where you want the files moved to:

```
find /foo/bar -type f -iname '*.srt' -exec sh -c '
    path="${1%/*}"; filename="${1##*/}";
    cp "${1}" "/foo/bar/${path##*/}.${filename}" ' sh_cp {} \;
```

If you’re putting this in a script,
you’ll want to make the starting directory parameterizable. 
But there’s a catch: the `cp` command is in a subshell
that has its own argument list. 
I believe that this approach is safe:

```
find "$1" -type f -iname '*.srt' -exec sh -c '
    path="${1%/*}"; filename="${1##*/}";
    cp "$1" "$2/${path##*/}.${filename}" ' sh_cp {} "$1" \;
```

This passes the starting directory, which is `$1` in the script,
into the subshell as a second argument, so it becomes `$2`.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't seem to do anything. I did some further digging on how my original script works, and noticed that in all of the downloads I have the subtitle folder is called `Subs`.  So I added `dir="${1%Subs/*}";` to my second line, and  changed `"${1}" "${path%/*}/${path##*/}.${filename}"` to `"${1}" "${dir%/*}/${path##*/}.${filename}"`. This seems to accomplish what I need, even if it isn't the most elegant solution.